# How to filter uniq rows and pipe data for some columns for those rows using unix?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

Below is how my file looks like-

```
User,Rights,Login_date
A,Admin,12-SEP-23
A,Accountant,01-SEP-23
B,Admin,05-SEP-23
B,Clerk,31-AUG-23
```

=============================

Expected output after filter should be-

```
User   Rights     Login_date
A,Admin|Accountant,12-SEP-23
B,Admin|Clerk,05-SEP-23
```

I am able to filter the duplicates but unable to pipe the rights.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBcug.png)

Comment: Don't expect readers to goto external sites to understand your problem (no image links please). Copy paste/your code into the body of your question and use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu to format as `code/data/output/errMsgs`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Ruby with the built-in CSV parser that does that:

```
ruby -r csv -e 'data=CSV.parse($<.read,**{:headers=>true})
puts data.headers.join("\t")
puts CSV.generate{|csv|
    data.group_by{|row| row["User"]}.each{|k,v|
        rights=v.map{|row| row["Rights"]}.join("|")
        csv<<[v[0]["User"],rights,v[0]["Login_date"]]
    }
}    
' file
```

Prints:

```
User    Rights  Login_date
A,Admin|Accountant,12-SEP-23
B,Admin|Clerk,05-SEP-23
```

Comment: Need help with unix shell scripting